# I'm an Italian; can my wife stay in Italy for 6 months without establishing residency?

Tags: visa, eu-spouses, italy, italy-aire

Ciao amici! I am an Italian citizen residing in the United States. My wife is an American. Our marriage is transcribed in Italy and at my consulate in the US. We want to return to Italy this year for approximately 6 months. We will be traveling all over the country, visiting family, seeing the sights and home shopping; therefore, we cannot establish residency as required for a permesso di soggiorno as it's unlikely that we'll be in the same place longer than 8 days (let alone several months). At the end of our trip, we will return to our AIRE registered home in the US.

Can my wife obtain an Italian D (national) visa for tourism in order to legally overstay the 90-day Schengen limitations - without establishing residency? If not, what do I need to do so my wife can accompany me on this trip?

Grazie mille!

Answer (score 1):

> At the end of our trip, we will return to our AIRE registered home in the US.

Since it is not your intention to take up residence in Italy, you should take the advice shown below and contact the competent Italian Embassy/Consulate.

The site will list all Italian consulates in the United States.

> [Il visto per l'Italia - Ministry of Foreign Affairs and International Cooperation](https://vistoperitalia.esteri.it/home/en)
> **Summary of information entered**
>
> - Nationality: UNITED STATES OF AMERICA
> - Residence: UNITED STATES OF AMERICA
> - Length of stay:  More than 90 days
> - Reason for stay: Family reasons
>
> **Note**: in the case of visa applications submitted by the family members (spouses, children or parents) of citizens of Italy or other European Union Member States, **we suggest you contact the competent Italian Embassy/Consulate**.